# Visual Studio Team Services with external git

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

Is it possible to use visual studio team services online with an on-premises git repository (non-tfs) while still using work item tracking. Currently I only get so far to add an external git repository to the build pipeline. But it seems that there is no way to use work item management and the other features. Is it still true ([read this here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/3607425-external-git-server-but-use-tfs-work-items)) that the only way to have on-premises git is to have an on-premises TFS server?

Comment: Why do you want a local Git repo?

Comment: Because we already have a fully configured git server (with backups and stuff like that) and especially to calm down management! They don't feel good putting code online. ;)

Comment: Then explain the functionality that they loose and let them decide if their irrational fear is worth the loss of functionality.

Comment: Yep, did that. Now we are doing everything on premises. ;) Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You can use work item tracking with an external Git provider, but you won't have any links or traceability to your commits. VSTS won't have any awareness of your source code.

You can, of course, host a Git repo in VSTS and add an additional remote to your local repo and push your code to both your external Git repo and your VSTS-hosted Git repo.

Comment: But how is that possible? Or did you mean that you can use it but that they are totally separated systems?